# Fill NAs of a column with condition of another column value in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, data-manipulation, fillna

I have employment status and salary as variables. I want to fill NAa of salary with 0 given unemployment=1 otherwise with mean of salary.

df.loc[df['salary'].isnull()] = np.where(df['unemployed']==1, 0, df['salary'])

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Is there any way I can do such a conditional fillna?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems you're trying to fill columns in 'df' with columns from 'labor'. Do you have 2 different dataframes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: It was a typo, it is actually my df name. The problem is not with it though.